# Huion Tablet in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.04, drivers, tablet

Well I was able to work with my Huion 610 tablet for a long time on ubuntu 14.04, however, after a fresh install of 16.04, with Kernel 4.8, the reason to have the tablet where pressure and digital "brushes" on different art programs stopped working.  I've tried what other people have written for kernel 4.5 and everything went to hell to the point where I had to re-install.  Any help?